# How do you build and reference libpng?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, libpng

Downloaded the source and changed the configuration to Release Library x64 and hit build. It built all well and good and passed some test.

Then I referenced the libpng (and zlib to avoid some arbitary errors) in my project and it builds all well and good until I try to use any of the libpng functions. (I can use some of the typedefs)

**tldr; I get some random errors whenever I try to use any libpng functions**

Can't find much info about the libpng at all, maybe I should just give up and use a more user-friendly library?

**Edit:** I set Library Directories to include the path where libpng and zlib libraries are.
And added the library names to the Linker input (additional dependencies). Which I believe is the standard way to reference libraries in Visual Studio

**Edit:**

```
png_const_bytep header[8]; 
FILE* fp = fopen("test.png", "rb");
fread(header, 1, 8, fp);
png_sig_cmp(*header, 0, 8); // <--- ERROR, compiles fine without
```

And some errors:

> 1. C4701: potentially uninitialized local variable 'sig_bit' used (in pngread.c)
> 2. C2220: warning treated as error - no 'executable' file generated (in pngread.c)
> 3. LNK1257: code generation failed

note that none of these are part of my code, but part of the libpng

Comment: Edited the question to include how I referenced the libraries in Visual Studio.

Comment: Perhaps you should describe the 'random errors'. To me it just sounds like you have bugs in your code, rather than there being anything wrong with the building or linking of the library.

Comment: Sure. I'll add a short description of my code. (and the errors)

Comment: Windows offers PNG support out of the box. See [Windows Imaging Component Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719654.aspx) for details.

Comment: Thanks @IInspectable I'm gonna have to take a look at that, but I really prefer being crossplatform compatible.

Could someone tell me why this is getting downvoted? I see it as a valid question I (and others) can't find answer for.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem exactly here. Had to rebuild libpng with "treat warnings as errors" switched off.
(even though libpng is a lib, my application was performing link-time code generation, so somehow generated errors off the library source code).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your libpng to the latest version (1.2.52, 1.5.18, or 1.6.9).  The problem with "sig_bit" has been fixed.